# Css transform + z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index

Yet another question about it, but I haven't found exactly the same problem on SO.

So I try to keep the z-index position of a child of the translated element.
See the issue here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjvLoW?editors=0100.

If you comment the line `transform: translateX(30%);` from div the z-index will work again.

So far I have tried to `translate3d()` to force re-rendering or opposite `transform-style: flat;` and many other stuff with no luck.

I know I can fix issue by translating the `p` element inside (instead of parent), but in my real complex context I can't.
Can someone give me a good tip?

Thank you for your help!

**[EDIT]**

I cannot set z-index on `div` element, it is not what I want since this div contains other elements that I want to be behind the `:before` background.

In the context of a sliding pane pushing content from left. I try to have only the pane above the overlay. not the right side content it also contains.

Here I have updated the codepen to better reflect my issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQBBoy?editors=0100

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use your code as usual just give `z-index: 0;` to the `div` element, because you given `position: relative;` it will stack the element by default.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/VmZZZV?editors=0100)